# How jQuery recognizes element after it has been moved?

Tags: jquery

Here is example http://codepen.io/g1un/pen/zKEBjg

```
function wrapme(){
  var box = $('.box');
  var top = box.scrollTop();
    $(document.body).wrapInner($("<div>", { class: "wrapper" }));
  box.scrollTop(top);
}
```

I'm interested in how does jquery execute this function right since I've saved in variable somethng whose parent was `body` and when the `scrollTop(top)` function runs it is applied on in fact another DOM element with `wrapper` parent.
I can't find the explanation of how jQuery notices this change.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly.

The `.box` element is always in the dom. The `wrapInner` function doesn't remove this element from the dom, so when you saved that element in the variable `.box` - you still have the exact element even after the call to `wrapInner`.

Regarding the `top` - again, the value is saved and afterwards applied back (to the relevant element).

Check this example:

```js
$('.box').scrollTop(1000);

function wrapme(){
  var box = $('.box');
  var top = box.scrollTop();
  console.log("Top: " + top);
  $(document.body).wrapInner($("<div>", { class: "wrapper" }));
  box.scrollTop(top);
  console.log("Scroll element to "+top+" from top");
}
```

```css
.box {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов. Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но и перешагнул в электронный дизайн. Его популяризации в новое время послужили публикация листов Letraset с образцами Lorem Ipsum в 60-х годах и, в более недавнее время, программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
<button onclick="wrapme()">wrap me!</button>
```

### Update

The `wrapInner` doesn't "delete" the elements, it only moves them inside the dom tree. When you save a reference (jquery or vanilla javascript ref) to some node in the dom-tree, even if that element is moved inside the dom tree - you still have the reference to the relevant node. Note that even of you **remove** the node from the dom tree - if you still have reference to that node you can add it back to the dom tree and manipulate that node.

This example demonstrates moving/removing of elements inside the tree while keep reference to them:

```js
$('#btn1').click(function() {
  // remove the #el1 node from the DOM tree, but keep reference to that note
  el1 = $('#cont1 #el1').remove();
  if (el1.length) {
    // append the #el1 node to the #cont2 using the reference
    $('#cont2').append(el1);
    
    // add border to that node, using the reference
    el1.css('border', '1px solid black');
  }
});

$('#btn2').click(function() {
  // save reference to the #el2 node
  el2 = $('#cont1 #el2');
  if (el2.length) {
    // append the #el1 node to the #cont2 using the reference
    $('#cont2').append(el2);
    
    // add border to that node, using the reference
    el2.css('border', '1px solid black');
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
#cont1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#cont2 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
#cont1 #el1, #cont1 #el2 {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cont1">cont1
  <div id="el1">el1</div>
  <div id="el2">el2</div>
</div>
<div id="cont2">cont2
</div>

<button id="btn1">Click to move - using remove()</button>
<button id="btn2">Click to move - using append()</button>
```

> The `append` function uses the `appendChild` method. "If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the document, appendChild() moves it from its current position to the new position (there is no requirement to remove the node from its parent node before appending it to some other node)."[[1]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

Comment: Thanks. But it seems you just repeat what I've already mentioned. I see that things work so, but I want to know how.
How does the created object knows that 'his' DOM element has moved to another position in DOM tree? Does he monitor it and updating itself or some jQuery structure updates and influences created objects?
I'll be glad to read something about what is behind the scenes.

Comment: Check the update part of the answer. Let me know if now the explanation is better (there is a snippet there and also a citation from the MDN regarding the `appendChild` function).

Comment: I guess the reason I can't figure it out is lack of knowledge of js fundamental things. So it'll be better for me to return to this question when I overcome it. Thanks for you efforts.

Comment: And if you want to ask something more specific I can try to explain.